# Gitlab pipeline fail to build due to project dependency to local dll

Tags: c#, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to learn Gitlab CI/CD and am struggling with a local dependency that I use in my project.

The project file looks like this

```
...    
<ItemGroup>
   <Reference Include="Cryptography">
      <HintPath>..\..\cryptography_dll\bin\Debug\Cryptography.dll</HintPath>
   </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
...
```

The .gitlab-ci.yml looks like this:

```
before-script:
  script:
    dotnet restore

build-job:       # This job runs in the build stage, which runs first.
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Compiling the code in $project..."
    - dotnet build $solution
    - echo "Compile complete."
```

The pipeline fails at "dotnet build .." since the Cryptography dll file isn't downloaded.
Here is the error message I get when i try to run the build command from Gitlab runner folder

> c:\GitLab-Runner\builds\ENPBGBAm\0\stp-dev\fixengine\FixEngineLibrary\Isec\FixEngine\Service\impl\AppConfigReader.cs(35
> ,61): error CS0103: The name 'Cryptography' does not exist in the
> current context [c:\GitLab-Runner\builds\ENPBGBAm\0\s
> tp-dev\fixengine\FixEngineLibrary\FixEngineLibrary.csproj]

How do I best solve this? Can I include the Cryptography.dll file in the git repo and copy the file disk using script commands in the pipeline? I am fairly new to both C# and Gitlab CI/CD so a simple solution would be appreciated.